# Nginx seem to ignore caching settings

Tags: nginx

I have the following `location`:

```
location /content/ {
  proxy_cache my_cache;
  proxy_cache_valid any 3m;
  proxy_cache_revalidate on;
  proxy_cache_min_uses 3;
  proxy_cache_lock on;
  proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control Vary;
  proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```

And the `cache-path` configuration:

```
  proxy_cache_methods GET HEAD;
  proxy_cache_path
    /var/cache/nginx
    levels=1:2
    keys_zone=my_cache:3m
    max_size=4g
    inactive=360m;
```

I run this script to test my `location`:

```
# for x in {1..1000}; do curl -sD- http://172.30.3.19/content/tst.txt; sleep .3; done

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 21 Feb 2018 13:14:12 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 8
Last-Modified: Wed, 21 Feb 2018 13:13:54 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "5a8d7092-8"
Accept-Ranges: bytes

test 01
```

And then I keep changing contents of the `tst.txt` which just doesn't seem to be cached.

What could be the problem?

Cache directory:

```
# ls -ld /var/cache/nginx/
drwx------ 2 www-data www-data 4096 May 23  2017 /var/cache/nginx/
```

Nginx process:

```
# ps -elf | grep nginx
5 S root      1983     1  0  80   0 - 50344 -      12:18 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
5 S www-data  2292  1983  0  80   0 - 51114 -      13:06 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
5 S www-data  2293  1983  0  80   0 - 51114 -      13:06 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
5 S www-data  2294  1983  0  80   0 - 51114 -      13:06 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
5 S www-data  2295  1983  0  80   0 - 51114 SyS_ep 13:06 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
5 S www-data  2296  1983  0  80   0 - 50344 -      13:06 ?        00:00:00 nginx: cache manager process
0 S root      2351  2050  0  80   0 -  2043 wait_w 13:10 pts/2    00:00:00 less nginx.conf
0 S root      2375  2068  0  80   0 -  3182 -      13:17 pts/4    00:00:00 grep nginx
```

`Nginx` version:

```
# nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.10.3
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fPIC' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_slice_module --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_perl_module=dynamic --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/headers-more-nginx-module --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-cache-purge --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-development-kit --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-echo --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/ngx-fancyindex --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nchan --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-lua --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-upload-progress --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have misunderstood the concept on Nginx' caching abilities.

As far as you have described your scenario you are serving static content. Here you can set proper caching headers for other caching systems as browsers, CDN or proxy servers. Additionally you didn't get a performance boost if you cache static content from your hard disk on your hard disk.

If you want to use Nginx' caching abilities you have to set a origin. This is a service where the cached content is coming from. You can use a HTTP server ([Nginx proxy module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass)) or a fast_cgi backend ([Nginx FastCGI module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_cache)).

But you can address the proxy_pass directive to Nginx itself:

```
server {
  listen *:80;
  location /content/ {
    proxy_cache   my_cache;
    proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:8080;
  }
}
server {
  listen  *:8080;
  root    /var/www/my-site.com;
  location /content/ {
    expires     3m;
    try_files   $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, after some trial and error I've figured that in order to benefit from the `proxy_cache` directive I must use `proxy_pass`. The goal here is to take content from the slower medium (`NFS` in my case) and cache it on the faster medium, like `SSD`, on the same server where `nginx` is running.

Comment: You didn't provide this essential information in your question. You should look for NFS caching solutions on the filesystem level, they work much better for these kinds of setups.